# Change background of the behind layer of popover

Tags: swift, popover

I have a real annoying problem with popover. The theme of my app is light (the labels in status bar is black), when I opened the popover, the labels in status bar gets white and the background of the behind layer page gets completely white, which is not good at all - see the screen shot

[image: screenshot]

here is how I opened the popover

```
  let vc = EditMeasurmentViewController(id: id)
  let nc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
  nc.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
  present(nc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And in some page when I added this line of code, the labels in status bar gets black again, but it won't work in every page... I don't know why

```
 modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = true
```

It would be great if I can change the behind layer background from white to black (the part that I show with an arrow), it solves my problem and also gives a good looking to the app.
could anyone help me on that?

Comment: I need really help here

Comment: Why don't you place a plain `UIView` with a black background over the main view when you show the popover guy?

Comment: over the main view of the background page?

Comment: Did you find a solution to that problem?